# Use of "in" while declaring JS variables

Tags: javascript, variables

Thanks in advance for your patience... Really trying to fill in weird gaps in my JS knowledge...

Analyzing other people's scripts and came across:

```
Var isTouch = "ontouchstart" in window;
```

What is the "in window" part doing? I've googled several basic variable declaration tutorials and it's not mentioned, and "in" is such a basic word, it's been hard to find answers.

Thanks,

JK

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/in_Operator

Comment: Thanks Alexander -- the Mozilla resource is great. Thanks Keoki, I think what I was missing was the term "operator" in my search, so now I know that much little more about JS so thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `someString in someObject` returns a boolean indicating whether the object has a property by that name.
[*Spec*](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.8.7)

Your code, other than having a miscapitalized `Var`, sets `isTouch` to `true` if `window` has an `ontouchstart` property.

Comment: Ah, totally makes sense and didn't realize you could examine an object that way. Thanks for the "Var" note too. I actually typed that as "var" but iOS tried to help me and I didn't catch it. =) Thanks for the clarification on "in".

Answer (score 1):

`isTouch` is now simply a boolean (true or false), as the `in` operator returns a boolean:

```
var foo = {
   bar : 42
},

hasBar  = 'bar'  in foo,  // true
hasFoob = 'foob' in foo;  // false
```

Comment: Thanks -- in hindsight, it's quite simple and elegantly written, I just hadn't seen code that used that single line approach to documenting whether certain features were available in the environment.